# Why ssh "password" prompt takes too long to appear?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

When I try to connect ssh it takes too long (almost 2 minutes) to appear password prompt.

Why does this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is something that comes wrong from Ubuntu's installation.

To fix it you have to change this line in **/etc/nsswitch.conf**:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

And change it for this one:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

Comment: The filename is /etc/nsswitch.conf.